# Efficient array elements un-ordering in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I just wanted to know what is the best way to un-order the elements in an ordered array in Java, 
Thanks

Comment: By unorder, I assume you mean shuffle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180979/using-collections-api-to-shuffle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)? If not that, you will need to give us more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: And you can be fairly sure that the shuffle algorithm of the Collections.shuffle() is pretty good. The standard JavaSE api is incredibly well tested. (Whoa... didn't want to sound like a sell speech)

Answer (score 2):

You want to shuffle that array using [a good algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Example_implementations).

I would trust [Collections#shuffle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) to implement this properly. If you need it to work on the array directly, implement the algorithm in your own helper method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much Java, so there may be better way, but this'll do the trick nicely.

[Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Example_implementations) from Wikipedia:

```
static Random rng = new Random();
public static void shuffle(int[] array) {
    // i is the number of items remaining to be shuffled.
    for (int i = array.length; i > 1; i--) {
        // Pick a random element to swap with the i-th element.
        int j = rng.nextInt(i);  // 0 <= j <= i-1 (0-based array)
        // Swap array elements.
        int tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i-1];
        array[i-1] = tmp;
    }
}
```