# Why does Collections.shuffle() fail for my array?

Tags: java, shuffle, random-access

Why does my code not work?

```
package generatingInitialPopulation;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class TestShuffle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The result is: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.

I was expecting a **randomly shuffled sequence**.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` can't be applied to arrays of primitive type as you expect. When applied to `int[]`, `Arrays.asList()` produces a list of `int[]`s instead of list of `Integer`s. Therefore you shuffle a newly created list of `int[]`.

This is a subtle behaviour of variadic arguments and generics in Java. `Arrays.asList()` is declared as

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

So, it can take several arguments of some type `T` and produce a list containing these arguments, or it can take one argument of type `T[]` and return a list backed by this array (that's how variadic arguments work).

However, the latter option works only when `T` is a reference type (i.e. not a primitive type such as `int`), because only reference types may be used as type parameters in generics (and `T` is a type parameter).

So, if you pass `int[]`, you get `T` = `int[]`, and you code doesn't work as expected. But if you pass array of reference type (for example, `Integer[]`), you get `T` = `Integer` and everything works:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[10]; 

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    arr[i] = i; 
} 

Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr)); 

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
}
```

Comment: WOW!!! But everyone said that the changes applied for the list, not with the array arr. Why does this work?

Comment: Because Arrays.asList() creates a new list that is backed by the array. It does not copy the array as others have stated. Every change to the list returned by Arrays.asList() also changes the array backing it.

Comment: Understood now. But why that doesn;t work with the primitive types?

Comment: @Dmitry: Because Java generics don't work with primitive types. See, `Arrays.asList()` returns `List<T>`, but you can't declare `List<int>` in Java.

Comment: T cannot be a primitive type, so in a sense this shouldn't compile for a primitive type.  However, because of the varargs, it is valid to call asList with a single object, and it will treat it as an array of size 1.  As such, it will compile and work in a confusing way.

Comment: @axtavt I was debugging this code, and found that code is not going inside for loop mentioned in below code.public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
        int size = list.size();
        if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
            for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
                swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
        }

Comment: To add to what @ILMTitan said, to create a a list from an array which is not backed by that array you should use List l = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr)); to create a LinkedList simply change ArrayList to LinkedList

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this line of code to your test:

```
List l=Arrays.asList(arr);
System.out.println(l);
```

You will see you are printing out a single element `List`.

Using `Arrays.asList` on a primitive array cause `asList` to treat the `int[]` as a single object rather than an array. It returns a `List<int[]>` instead of a `List<Integer>`. So, you are basically shuffling a single element `List` and so nothing really gets shuffled.

Notice that some of the answers already given are wrong because `asList` returns a List backed by the original array, nothing gets copied - all changes are reflected in the orginal array.

Comment: But why does this work in a such way with the primitive type int(treats int[] as a single object)?

Comment: @Dmitry: Arrays are also `Object`s in Java and I guess the arguments of `asList(T...)` is interpreted as simple a single `Object`, since `asList` does not expect primitives.

Answer (score -2):

That doesn't work because the call to `shuffle` is operating on the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList`, not on the underlying array. Thus, when you iterate over the array to print out the values, nothing has changed. What you want to do is save a reference to the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList`, and then print out the values of that `List` (rather than the values of the array) after you `shuffle` it.

Comment: The API says - "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)" - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Comment: Thank you for the immediate answer!

Comment: Wrong, any changes made to the list created by `Arrays.asList()` is made to the array itself - the list uses that array to store the elements. The problem is that `asList` can not create a list of primitives, so it creates a list with one element: the array itself. It would work for an array with non-primitives (e.g. Integer).

Answer (score -3):

Store the list resturned by Arrays.asList and shuffle that...

```
List myShuffledList = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.shuffle(myShuffledList);
```

Comment: it's much better to use generic types instead of raw types