# I'm getting strange output from java program

Tags: java, random

I've some strange situation here and i thought that you may help me. I have an int array populated with numbers from 1 to 10. I want to generate random number from this array and save it to another int array. I used class Random to pick any number and since random throws 0 also i modify it like that ( so it throws numbers from 1 to 10 )

```
randNum = rand.nextInt(numbers.length-min+1)+min;
```

Following code makes sure that if it generates same random number, it skips it. Program is actually working and i'm getting in another array randomly positioned numbers from 1 to 10. That's what i wanted. But sometimes i'm missing one number from 1 - 10 AND iam Getting ZERO instead. Why??

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] usednum = new int[10];
Random rand = new Random();
int randNum;
int min = 1;

for (int x = 0; x<numbers.length; x++) {        
  for (int i = 0; i<usednum.length; i++) { 
    randNum = rand.nextInt(numbers.length-min+1) + min;
    for (int f = 0; f<usednum.length; f++) {
      if (usednum[f] == randNum) {
        break;
      } else if (usednum[f] == 0) { 
        usednum[x] = randNum;   
      }
    }
  } 
}

for (int c = 0; c<usednum.length; c++) {
  System.out.println(usednum[c]);
}
```

Comment: I have run this and confirmed that there is an error.

Comment: What is the purpose of `g`? you assign it, but do not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're inner-most `for` loop only checks if the current random number is in the `usednum[]` array. And the `for` loop immediately outer of that only checks **10 times total**. It gives up too quickly because it only tries 10 random numbers. If all 10 are already used, nothing will get stored in that slot of `usednum[]` (thus it will be **0**), try adding a `while` loop around that and get rid of the extraneous outer-most `for` loop:

```
        for(int i = 0; i<usednum.length; i++) {
           while(usednum[i]==0) {
              randNum = rand.nextInt(numbers.length-min+1)+min;
              for(int f = 0; f<usednum.length; f++) {
                 if(usednum[f] == randNum) {
                    break;
                 } //if                                                                                                                                        
                 else if (usednum[f] == 0) {
                    usednum[i] = randNum;
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

Also note that the assignment is for `usednum[i] = randNum;`.

This is essentially replacing the middle `for` loop (the one that goes from i=0 to 9) with the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is simply to shuffle an array of numbers, try this instead:

```
Integer[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

It will have the same effect. Unless you are completing a homework assignment that forces you to solve the issue in a more manual fashion, just make use of the standard Java libraries.

The `shuffle` method writes changes through to the underlying `Integer` array, thanks to the special type of `List` returned by `Arrays.asList(...)`. Note you have to use an array of `Integer` not `int` (see [Why does Collections.shuffle() fail for my array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981420/collections-shuffle)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as you said i must complete my homework in hard way, lol. It's stupid tho..

Comment: Well, it's difficult enough to have challenged you, which is a good thing! In the future, please mark such questions with the "homework" tag so that people answer your question in a more constructive manner.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - followed it and re-wrote it:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }));
        int[] usednum = new int[10];
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = numbers.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int randNum = rand.nextInt(numbers.size());
            usednum[i]=numbers.get(randNum);
            numbers.remove(randNum);
        }
        for (int c:usednum) {
            System.out.println(c); 
        }
```

Comment: Edited - please review again - sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You are generating used numbers through an entire pass, so it doesn't generate a zero is just fails to generate a value it should.

Comment: I think this makes some sense yes. And why exactly fails to generate a value?

Comment: It generates 10 values all of which have been used before. Try using `randNum = 4;` in your code it will give you 4 then 9 zeros

Answer (score 0):

you have one for loop too much.

remove the loop with the i iterator and the program should do what you want.

Oh and remove the -min+1 from the random generator, -1+1=0

Comment: the -min+1 is probably there to be used in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your array `usednum` is consisted of zeros at the beginning. In some cases, your program doesn't change that initial value, but breaks before at the line:

```
if(usednum[f] == randNum)
```

and does that during all iterations with same value `x`. `X` increments and there goes your chance to change the zero value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are never using the content of the array `numbers`. Try changing the array to something like `int[] numbers = { 10, 22, 23, 42, 53, 18, 7, 8, 93, 10 };`. You will get similar output.

[Jon Lin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12217339/887149) describe why your code is not working but does not address this issue. I think you will want to change your code to something like:

```
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int[] usednum = new int[10];
    Random rand = new Random();

    int selectedCount = 0;

    while (selectedCount < numbers.length) {
        int randNum = numbers[rand.nextInt(numbers.length)];
        boolean contains = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < selectedCount; x++) {
            if (usednum[x] == randNum) {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!contains) {
            usednum[selectedCount] = randNum;
            selectedCount++;
        }
    }


    for (int c = 0; c < usednum.length; c++) {
        System.out.println(usednum[c]);
    }
```