# Quickest way to randomize an array of ints in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

Is it possible to choose a random element from one array and move it to another without the aid of ArrayLists/Collections etc (unless you can use shuffle on an array)? and making sure that element isn't selected again?
I thought about setting it to null seems you cannot remove it but I'm unsure.

Basically i want `myArray` to get shuffled or randomized and I figured the best way would be to pull them from one in a random order and add them to a new one...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981420/collections-shuffle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Collections.shuffle(List)` to shuffle an array as well:

```
Integer[] data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(data));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

will print e.g. [6, 2, 4, 5, 10, 3, 1, 8, 9, 7].

`Arrays.asList` will not create a new list, but a List interface wrapper for the array, so that changes to the list are propagated to the array as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method to shuffle a list.

Answer (score 2):

**-** You can use a `Collection` like `List` and then use `shuffle()` method.

**-** Or if you want to stick with the Array then first you need to **convert the array into List and then use shuffle() method.**

**Eg:**

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[10];

List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList());

Collections.shuffle(i);
```