# Getting random and unique number from a list of Integers. Array method

Tags: java, arrays

```
private int[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

what code should i use to get randomly but unique number from this list.
Please provide me the simplest way i am a beginner.
Thank you for help.

Comment: If you are randomly picking numbers, you could get the same number every time, therefore no longer being unique?

Comment: what do you mean with "unique" ??

Comment: means if i take 9 from the list the next number will not be 9 until the list is used up and no more number is available

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) "Please provide me ..." is not the beginning of a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickest way to randomize an array of ints in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625997/quickest-way-to-randomize-an-array-of-ints-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Integer[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(list));
```

Comment: `list` is a `int[]`, `Arrays.asList(list)` will return a `List` with size 1. Shuffling a list with size 1 is a no-op. Would only work, if `list` were a `Integer[]`.

Comment: after implementing this. how do i return the number one by one maybe         ((the 1st no. in the list then the 2nd no. and so on)) and parse it into a variable. thank you for helping.

Comment: @user2016977 You can access the original array with `list[i]` (where `i` is the index you want, i.e. 0 or 1 for the 1st and the 2nd respectively) as usual.

Comment: @user2016977 You can use it same as int[] list . list[0] for fisrt number in the list , list[1] for second number in the list and so on...

Comment: @user2016977 You can tick my answer if it works exactly the way you wanted .:)

Comment: i cannot seem to upvote anyone "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: I am sorry maybe it is my bad that i couldnt explain properly...the list is being randomized but i want the number off my list once i have take it by calling list[1], then next time i call list[1] i will not get the same number again

Answer (score 6):

Change your declaration to:

```
private Integer[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

and then execute in any method of your class since the variable is `private`:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(list);
Collections.shuffle(l);
```

This will resort all the list randomly, so it will do what you want.

Note that it will also affect your original array `list` since the list returned from the `Arrays.asList` call will use your array internally.

Comment: @user2016977.. And this will give you duplicates also.

Comment: this won't compile, as `Collections.shuffle()` is a `void` method.

Comment: how do i implement this in my code. Just copy paste?

Comment: @AdriánLópez: No. You removed the compiler error, but the code still doesn't do what you want it to, as `list` is a `int[]`, `Arrays.asList(list)` will return a List with size 1. Shuffling a list with size 1 is a no-op. Would only work, if `list` were a `Integer[]`. Try to run your code and look at the output.

Comment: @AdriánLópez: copying your code under his declaration will be the next compiler error. His `list` is a `private` instance variable and your code can only be inside a method or constructor (or initializer block).

Comment: @jlordo -_- you're right again. That's easy to notice if he's using an IDE though...

Comment: I see the question about why code won't compile, that we later find out it's not inside a method, about once a day here on SO. I guess the people asking also use an IDE.

Comment: 1) you need to `shuffle(l)` not `shuffle(list)`, 2) after you `shuffle(l)` you don't need `list = l.toArray();` since shuffle was operating on original references from `list` that ware placed into `l` so basically you need to just `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(list));` if list is `Integer[]`

Comment: @AdriánLópez: Also, it would be good for you to use an IDE, as your code is still wrong. It gives following compiler error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to Integer[]` in the last line (which is not needed at all).

Comment: @Pshemo fixed 1) thx (error came from another fix that I did on a hurry :/) 2) I knew, but I still prefer to keep it this way for clarity

Comment: @AdriánLópez: You prefer compiler errors for clarity??

Comment: @jlordo Shouldn't give any error from the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29

Comment: Put it in your IDE and it would tell you `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to Integer[]`. To avoid it, you have to write `list = l.toArray(new Integer[l.size()]);`, but that would be a total waste of memory, as the shuffling is reflected to the original array.

Comment: @AdriánLópez: Your [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])) is to `toArray(T[] a)` which returns `T[]` but you are using `toArray()`, which returns `Object[]`, [link here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray())

Comment: Fine, you changed my mind then. Definetly not worh it just for clarity. OP: sorry for the typos. @jlordo I'm obviously not using any IDE for writing 3 lines... I was refering to the OP probably using it.

Comment: @AdriánLópez: I recommend next time to use an IDE for 3 lines, as looking at our chat you had 5 errors in those 3 lines. Everybody who upvoted didn't look at your solution good enough.

Comment: @jlordo yeah not gonna do it. I'm trying to help from time to time whenever I can but opening my IDE for such a simple question (since I wasn't coding atm) is a waste of my time . I recognize my errors and thanks for pointing them out. However, I really think that my original answer was more than enough to show the OP a way to do it (A simple link to the `Collections.shuffle` would have probably given me plenty of upvotes) Anyway, this is too offtopic and doesn't belong here, so the discussion is over for me. Again, thanks for pointing the errors.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you do a [shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and then select numbers in the order they are placed in the shuffled result.

Answer (score 0):

The general algorithm used in these kinds of scenarios is to return the `index` that is a `random number modulo length of the array`

Comment: @ whoever who downvoted. please have a look at this.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below:

```
public static boolean empty(Integer[] list){
    for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++){
        if(list[i] != null){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    Random r = new Random();
    int index = 0;
    while(!empty(list)){
        index = r.nextInt(list.length);
        if(list[index] != null){
            System.out.println(list[index]);
            list[index] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate a random integer between 0 and the last index of the list, print the item at that index if it's not null, then make that item null. The static function 'empty', checks to see if every item in the array is null (i.e. every item has been seen). When 'empty' returns true, the 'while' loop terminates. The reason the 'Integer' type is used instead of 'int' is that 'int' variables cannot be null, whereas 'Integer' variables can.

The 'empty' function searches the array one index at a time and returns false immediately if it finds a non-null index. This is a time-saving mechanism that means that the function won't perform any unnecessary searching. If that loop completes fully then we know that no non-null entry has been found, so true is returned.

Comment: Yes i will try this method thank you very much for taking the time to help me.